# When should one close a SolrSearcher?

Tags: solr, solr4

I am implementing a Solr component (implementing org.apache.solr.handler.component.SearchComponent). When overriding prepare() method, I retrieve the searcher via: responseBuilder.req.getSearcher() which returns a SolrIndexSearcher instance.

My question: am I supposed to close the searcher at the end of the prepare() method?

I am not the one opening the searcher. So I should not be the one closing it. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you shouldn't close the searcher.

Searchers have to be closed and opened again if the index data has changed. So they might have quite a long lifetime.
Since your component ist read-only (I assume), this isn't your responsibility. The update components will care about this.

You can have a look at the `org.apache.solr.handler.component.QueryComponent`. It also doesn't close the searcher.